# Default Django checkbox to be true and hidden

Tags: django, checkbox, newsletter, satchmo

I am working with Satchmo and am wondering for the newsletter subscription, how to make it so when people sign up, they are automatically subscribed to the newsletter. I found this line of code in `forms.py`:

```
newsletter = forms.BooleanField(label=_('Receive Daily Deals'),
    widget=forms.CheckboxInput(), required=False)
```

I am assuming that in the `widget` there, I can add something to make it automatically be true and hidden.

Comment: Isn't that wrong? if it is hidden people can't un-select it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
newsletter = forms.BooleanField(label=_('Receive Daily Deals'),
    widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False, initial=True)
```

Comment: This will render the checkbox unusable

Comment: This render input type as "hidden" not "checkbox"

Answer (score 5):

You can make checkbox hidden with adding a class to element shown as below:

```
// css
// .hidden { display: none;}

newsletter = forms.BooleanField(
    label=_('Receive Daily Deals'),
    widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'hidden'}), 
    required=False, 
    initial=True
)
```